# Tastypie can't serialize ForeignKey fields

Tags: python, tastypie

I have 3 model: BzMediaMusician, BzMediaSinger and BzMediaAlbum.
BzMediaAlbum has 2 fields id_singer and id_musician related to 2 model BzMediaMusician, BzMediaSinger.

In here id_singer and id_musician can be null because some album don't have

```
id_singer = models.ForeignKey('BzMediaSinger', null=True, blank=True, db_column='id_singer')
id_musician = models.ForeignKey('BzMediaMusician', null=True, blank=True, db_column='id_musician')
```

I have request to httpx://localhost:8000/api/album/ to get result

```
{
"meta": {
"limit": 20,
"next": "/api/album/?limit=20&offset=20",
"offset": 0,
"previous": null,
"total_count": 501
},
"objects": [
{
"album_cat": "69",
"album_name_ascii": "truong ca kinh pho mon",
"album_viewed": 1618,
"album_viewed_month": 0,
"des": "Võ Tá Hân phổ nhạc",
"id_album": 7,
"name_en": "",
"name_vn": "Trường ca kinh Phổ Môn",
"order": "1",
"pic_thumb": "http://local.com/nhac/img/truong_ca_kinh_pho_mon.jpg",
"resource_uri": "/api/album/7/"
},]
```

As result above it don't contain id_singer and id_musician.
All i need is have full info of musician and singer in that 2 fields.
Please help.

Model

```
class BzMediaMusician(models.Model):
    id_musician = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name_full = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dignity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    des_vn = models.TextField()
    des_en = models.TextField()
    content_vn = models.TextField()
    content_en = models.TextField()
    pic_thumb = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pic_full = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    show_list = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    enabled = models.IntegerField()
    nhacsi_type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    nhacsi_name_ascii = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bz_media_musician'


class BzMediaSinger(models.Model):
    id_singer = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_full = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dignity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    des_vn = models.TextField()
    des_en = models.TextField()
    content_vn = models.TextField()
    content_en = models.TextField()
    pic_thumb = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pic_full = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    show_list = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    enabled = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.IntegerField()
    singer_name_ascii = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bz_media_singer'


class BzMediaAlbum(models.Model):
    id_album = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_vn = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    des = models.TextField()
    order = models.BigIntegerField()
    enabled = models.IntegerField()
    id_group = models.BigIntegerField()
    id_parent = models.BigIntegerField()
    id_singer = models.ForeignKey('BzMediaSinger', null=True, blank=True, db_column='id_singer')
    id_musician = models.ForeignKey('BzMediaMusician', null=True, blank=True, db_column='id_musician')
    pic_thumb = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    top_album = models.IntegerField()
    album_name_ascii = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    album_viewed = models.IntegerField()
    album_viewed_month = models.IntegerField()
    album_player = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    album_cat = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bz_media_album'
```

Resource

```
  class BzMediaSingerResource(MyModelResource):
        class Meta:
            filtering = {
                "enabled": ALL,
                "name_full": ALL,
            }
            ordering = ['order']
            queryset = BzMediaSinger.objects.filter(enabled=1)
            resource_name = 'singer'


    class BzMediaMusicianResource(MyModelResource):
        class Meta:
            filtering = {
                "enabled": ALL,
                "name_full": ALL,
            }
            ordering = ['order']
            queryset = BzMediaMusician.objects.filter(enabled=1)
            resource_name = 'musician'


    class BzMediaAlbumResource(MyModelResource):
        class Meta:
            filtering = {
                "enabled": ALL,
                "album_cat": ALL,
                "name_vn": ALL,
                "pic_thumb": ALL,
                "id_group": ALL,
                "id_parent": ALL,
            }
            ordering = ['order']
            excludes = ['enabled', 'album_player', 'top_album', 'id_group', 'id_parent']
            queryset = BzMediaAlbum.objects.filter(enabled=1)
            resource_name = 'album'
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `fields.ForeignKey` with `null=True`?